# Android: How to completely hide System bar in a tablet?

Tags: android, navigationbar

I have a tablet which is rooted. To hide the navigation as well as the system bar I have the following code in my Activity's onCreate method:

```
final int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE;


        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        {

            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);

            // Code below is to handle presses of Volume up or Volume down.
            // Without this, after pressing volume buttons, the navigation bar will
            // show up and won't hide
            final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
            decorView
                .setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility)
                    {
                        if((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0)
                        {
                            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
```

I want to not allow the user the option to pull the System Bar at all. For rooted device. how do I go about it?

Answer (score 2):

Here are two very simple calls to disable and enable the status bar that I have used before. Can be used from the command line

**Disable:**

```
service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui
```

**Enable:**

```
am startservice -n com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService
```

Comment: tell me if you are facing any issue @Ritu Raj